# Getting error: update rubygems while deploying/migrating to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, heroku, bundler

I am getting the following error when migrating to Heroku.

> `Installing hoe (2.9.4) /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:170:in >`install': hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself. (Gem::InstallError)`

It sais that the ruby gems version is out of date. Somebody knows how i could solve this problem?

using rails 3.0.5 with ruby 1.9.2

`bundler`

```
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using RedCloth (4.2.2) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.5) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.5) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.2) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.26) 
Using actionpack (3.0.5) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.17) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.5) 
Using arel (2.0.9) 
Using activerecord (3.0.5) 
Using activeresource (3.0.5) 
Using archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2) 
Using authlogic (2.1.6) 
Using xml-simple (1.0.15) 
Using aws-s3 (0.6.2) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4) 
Using block_helpers (0.3.3) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using columnize (0.3.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2) 
Using json (1.5.1) 
Using gherkin (2.3.6) 
Using term-ansicolor (1.0.5) 
Using cucumber (0.10.2) 
Using nokogiri (1.4.4) 
Using cucumber-rails (0.4.1) 
Using daemons (1.0.10) 
Using database_cleaner (0.6.7) 
Using factory_girl (1.3.3) 
Using faker (0.9.5) 
Using fastercsv (1.5.4) 
Using formtastic (1.2.3) 
Using gem_plugin (0.2.3) 
Using haml (3.0.25) 
Using hoe (2.9.4) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.5) 
Using rails (3.0.5) 
Using kaminari (0.12.0) 
Using ruby_core_source (0.1.5) 
Using linecache19 (0.5.12) 
Using meta_search (1.0.4) 
Using mongrel (1.2.0.pre2) 
Using paperclip (2.3.11) 
Using pg (0.11.0) 
Using pickle (0.4.7) 
Using populator (1.0.0) 
Using render_inheritable (1.0.0) 
Using rspec-core (2.5.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.5.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.5.0) 
Using rspec (2.5.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.5.0) 
Using ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25) 
Using ruby-debug19 (0.11.6) 
Using test-unit (1.2.3) 
Using will_paginate (3.0.pre2) 
Using typus (3.0.10) from https://github.com/fesplugas/typus.git (at master) 
Using webrat (0.7.3)
```

UPDATE:

`heroku stack`

```
aspen-mri-1.8.6
* bamboo-ree-1.8.7
bamboo-mri-1.9.2 (prepared, will migrate on next git push)
```

UPDATE2:

error trace

```
Installing hoe (2.9.4) /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:170:in `install': hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
   FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
!Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

Comment: are you running on the bamboo stack?

run heroku stack to see which stack it's set to.

Comment: It looks like it is out of date, no?

Comment: @ffoeg I updated my question. I want to migrate my stack to 1.9.2, but i have the same error message while doing ruby 1.8.7. @fl00r Yes i know but it is the rubygems on heroku its side and i dont know how to fix that.

Comment: updated with the full error trace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok i solved it.

hoe simply doesnt work with heroku because they dont support new versions of rubygems (this is such a pain with heroku)

I added the hoe gem here:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "hoe"
end
```

and typed the following in my console:

`heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"`

Comment: Glad you solved it. I was about to ask why hoe was in there! ;)

Comment: It is a dependency of unit-test. And i had that one  in the Gemfile.

Comment: I am running into the same issue but your solution didn't work for me. For some reason heroku was still trying to install `hoe` even though I followed your solution exactly.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile.lock? Maybe hoe get required in a gem you're having in production. You sure you typed the `heroku config:add` in your console?