# An error occured while installing wkhtmtopdf-heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku doesn't allow me to put airbrake and wkhtmlpdf-heroku gems together. My previous push works fine without airbrake. If I put airbrake again in my gemfile, the error below results:

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /tmp/build_li34yprz7arq/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/cache/wkhtmltopdf-heroku-1.0.0.gem. It may be corrupted.
   An error occurred while installing wkhtmltopdf-heroku (1.0.0), and Bundler
   cannot continue.
```

Do you know any reason why that's happening? Thanks!

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130669/heroku-zentest-and-rubygems

Answer (score 0):

The wkhtmltopdf-heroku gem just drops a wkhtmltopdf binary in your project and sets up configs for common 'client' gems.  You can just do that yourself manually.  I say this because I had some other odd issues tied to that gem that went away mysteriously when I just did setup for myself.

So try just dropping wkhtmltopdf-amd64 in your projects bin directory and do your own config.  In my case, for wicked_pdf, that meant a wicked_pdf.rb in /initializers containing

```
WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => (Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development? ? 'c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe' : Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s),
                 :page_size => 'Letter',
                 :outline => {:outline => true, :outline_depth => 4}}
```

Just to clarify, that is pointing to a windows binary on my C drive for test and production, and otherwise (meaning production) pointing to the amd-64 binary (for Heroku) which I have in the project's bin directory.

Comment: for production what will you do?

Comment: Production is the 'not test/dev' case, which points it to the binary that I put in the project's bin directory.  I don't love the solution, but it is the only thing that has worked reliably for me.   Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s